# jquery how to deserialize json object

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

How can you deserialize this json object below?

```
[{"id":"67","name":"TestString"}]
```

I tried to do this below but couldnt succeed...

```
success: function (data, status) {
          $.each(data, function (dt) {

              var mydata = data.d;

              alert(mydata); // returns [{"id":"67","name":"TestString"}]

              $("#txt_speciality").tokenInput("add", mydata.id);
          });
}
```

here is the way I am creating the json object

```
[WebMethod]
public static string get_specialities(string ProfessionalID)
{
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("Connection String2");
    DbCommand dbCommand;
    dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Select_Professionals_Speciality");
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "prof_id", DbType.Int16, Convert.ToInt16(ProfessionalID));
    IDataReader dr = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand);
    //[{ id: 3, name: "test3" }]
    string return_str="[";
    int i = 0;
    while (dr.Read()) {
        if (i > 0)
            return_str += ",";
        return_str += "{\"id\":\"" + dr["SpecialtyID"].ToString().Trim() + "\",\"name\":\"" + dr["SpecialtyName"].ToString().Trim() + "\"}";
        i++;
    }
    return_str += "]";
    return return_str;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you might be double json-encoding on the server-side.

Comment: Are you retrieving it as JSON or as text? Please share the rest of your AJAX call.

Comment: I am retrieving as text

Comment: Rather than writing the Json yourself (in your c#) you may find it easier, and less error prone, to use a tool like JSON.Net: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Comment: .net actually contains class for json handling: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
var mydata; // [{"id":"67","name":"TestString"}]

var json = $.parseJSON(mydata);
```

the json variable will contain the de-serialized json object

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ -- this will use `JSON.parse()` if it's available, and jQuery's own code if it's not.

Answer (score 7):

I assume this is what you need: JSON.parse(data)

```
success: function (data, status) {
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          $.each(data, function (dt) {

          var mydata = data.d;

          alert(mydata); // returns [{"id":"67","name":"TestString"}]

          $("#txt_speciality").tokenInput("add", mydata.id);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use jQuery, [here is the function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) However, any contemporal browser has function

```
JSON.parse()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're retrieving your data as text, it's not parsed as an array on arrival, but as a string.

Use [`.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getJSON) or `datatype:json` in your [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) options to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var object = JSON.parse(data);
```

Now you cann access all the atributes. For example object.id